# Not found because of proxy error: Error: certificate has expired when trying to do an axios Post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am getting `Not found because of proxy error: Error: certificate has expired when trying to do an axios Post`.

I am using the below code to get the Axios post request:

```
axios.post('https://35.163.140.105:9999/osm/admin/v1/tokens', postData, axiosConfig)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated');
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

Comment: This is working when I am trying to access via postman API.

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate? Does this happen on development mode, on production or both?